# Save 3 Columns of a Worksheet as CSV (with VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with visual basic, I would like to generate a csv with only 3 columns, it would be B M R, I have a code here but it is not only generating the 3 columns but the whole worksheet, could you help me?

```
Sub GravaTXT()
    Dim pasta As Workbook
    Dim abaPlan As Worksheet
    Dim b As Range
    Dim m As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim name As String
    name = Range("R13").Value

    Set b = ActiveCell.EntireColumn("B")
    Set m = ActiveCell.EntireColumn("M")
    Set r = ActiveCell.EntireColumn("R")
    Set abaPlan = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orcamento")
    Set pasta = Application.Workbooks.Add

    abaPlan.Copy Before:=pasta.Worksheets(pasta.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    pasta.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\alcir.scarmin\Desktop\" & name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    pasta.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**
I made a small modification (of @Pehs answer) to be able to run correctly, but the way I left it now it only takes the line "20" how can I make OffSet? I tried in several ways and it did not work. (I'm Brazilian, I'm using google translator, Brazilian people do not like to help themselves) Thank you.

```
Sub GravaTXT()
    Dim abaPlan As Worksheet
    Set abaPlan = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orcamento")

    Dim name As String
    name = abaPlan.Range("R13").Value

    Dim pasta As Workbook
    Set pasta = Application.Workbooks.Add


    abaPlan.Range("B20,M20,R20").Copy pasta.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    pasta.Worksheets(1).name = abaPlan.name

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    pasta.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\alcir.scarmin\Desktop\" & name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    pasta.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You are copying the entire sheet to a new workbook. It's no surprise it comes out as an entire sheet. If you want certain columns, create a blank sheet and copy those columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because you copied the whole worksheet with `abaPlan.Copy` but you only need to copy some columns `abaPlan.Range("B:B,M:M,R:R").Copy`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GravaTXT()
    Dim abaPlan As Worksheet
    Set abaPlan = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orcamento") 'source workbook

    Dim name As String
    name = abaPlan.Range("R13").Value 'always refer ranges to a specific worksheet

    Dim pasta As Workbook
    Set pasta = Application.Workbooks.Add

    'copy columns B, M and R to new workbook first worksheet
    abaPlan.Range("B:B,M:M,R:R").Copy pasta.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    pasta.Worksheets(1).Name = abaPlan.Name 'rename the first worksheet to the same name as abaPlan

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    pasta.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\alcir.scarmin\Desktop\" & name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    pasta.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

---

**Note**
I recommend to use

```
Filename:=Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & name & ".csv"
```

instead of a hard coded path.

Also be aware that using the `name` from  R13 without a check if it only contains characters that are valid for a filename could result in errors.

Comment: Why did you change it to `B20,M20,R20`? Of course then you only get these 3 cells. If you need the entire columns then stick to `B:B,M:M,R:R` as in my answer.